# ACTION_DIAL can't find an Intent when call button is being clicked

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using an `ImageView` to fetch the data from a `TextView` and use it to call the `ACTION_DIAL`. Whenever the app is run, it is unable to launch the dialer to display the number. It shows that the `getPackageManger` is null. I've added the code with the XML below. If I remove the else statement below the app will crash.

Code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class PostDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mTitleTv, mDetailTv, mCategoryTv, mCallTv;

    ImageView mImageIv;

    private static final String TAG = "PostDetailActivity";


    String contact;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_detail);

        //Action Bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        // ActionBar title
        actionBar.setTitle("Coupon Details");

        // Set Back Button
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


        // Initialise
        mTitleTv = findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
        mDetailTv = findViewById(R.id.descriptionTv);
        mImageIv = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mCategoryTv = findViewById(R.id.categoryTv);

        mCallTv = findViewById(R.id.callTv);

        // get data from intent
        String image = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        String desc = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
        String cate = getIntent().getStringExtra("category");

        String call = getIntent().getStringExtra("contact");

        contact = call;

        // Set Data to views
        mTitleTv.setText(title);
        mDetailTv.setText(desc);
        mCategoryTv.setText(cate);

        mCallTv.setText(call);

        Picasso.get().load(image).into(mImageIv);

    }

    // Handle onBack pressed to go back to the previous activity

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }


    public void dialNumber(View view) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.callTv);
        // Use format with "tel:" and phone number to create phoneNumber.
        String phoneNumber = String.format("",
                textView.getText().toString().trim());

//        String phoneNumber = "1234567890";

        // Create the intent.
        Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        // Set the data for the intent as the phone number.
        dialIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneNumber));
        // If package resolves to an app, send intent.
        if (dialIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(dialIntent);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't resolve app for ACTION_DIAL Intent.");
        }
    }

}
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:contentPadding="10dp"
    tools:context=".PostDetailActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageView"
            android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="73dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/titleTv"
            android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="73dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:text="This will be the description of the post" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoryTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/descriptionTv"
            android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="73dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:text="This will be the description of the post" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/callTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/descriptionTv"
            android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="73dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:text="This will be the description of the post" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCall"
            android:layout_width="19dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_marginStart="83dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="255dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="dialNumber"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call_black" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
String phoneNumber = String.format("", textView.getText().toString().trim());
```

with

```
 String phoneNumber = String.format("tel:%s", textView.getText().toString().trim());
```

As the first statement will produce an empty string.

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue, it still throws the log statement from the if statement.

Comment: Also add "tel:" before phone number